# T-SQL query to get role using role id in user table

Tags: sql-server, inner-join

Can some one please tell me how can i get record of user and it's role_desc. Following are my tables.

```
tblUSERS:   UserID PK
            Name
            RoleID FK

tblROLES:   RoleID PK
            Role_Desc
```

My query is as following

```
select Name,Role_Desc from tblUSERS
       inner join tblROLES on tblUSERS.RoleID = tblRoles.RoleID;
```

Let say i have record in tblUSER as following

```
1       Zeb      2
```

and in Roles table i have following records

```
1       Admin    
2       Supervisior
```

I want to get the following result

```
Zeb     Supervisior
```

Not result like following

```
Zeb     Admin
Zeb     Supervisior
```

Please give me your suggestions.. 
thanks in advance

Comment: I don't think there is nothing wrong with your query. One reason for the result could be that there are two users with the same name and one is admin and the other supervisitor.

Comment: It's impossible that that this sample data is giving you that result: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/277a4/2 . The only way is that you have two users called Zeb. One as supervisor and one as admin

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Based on creating the tables and data with [SqlFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/4cca0/1/0) it appears that your query is fine.**

It looks like you have a user with the same name with different roles and therefore you are seeing the result you are seeing.

Try running this query to confirm:

```
select UserID,Name,Role_Desc from tblUSERS
   inner join tblROLES on tblUSERS.RoleID = tblRoles.RoleID;
```

You might want to query off of the UserID since you know this will be unique.

Answer (score 1):

You can check the same user names (even the user id is different), with more than one roles assign, using below query.

Select COUNT(Name), NAME from tblUSERS   group by Name Having COUNT(Name)>1